# Symfony collection detach instead remove

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

is it possible whem element is removed from collection in front end to keep the item marked to remove in DB, only detached it from original object, so the reference to that object will be null?

It's done via Symfony basic collection remove/add way in front end. But no matter what I try, the entity, which user remove from the form in front end is deleted.

Even that I comment the code which actually remove it from collection, entity is still deleted.

```
/**
 * Remove address.
 *
 * @param Address $address
 */
public function removeAddress(Address $address)
{
    //$this->addresses->removeElement($address);
    $address->setContact(null);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have set some `cascade` or `orphanRemoval` option set. Do you use these options in your mapping?

Comment: Yes, there is cascade set for persist and remove. So simply delete remove cascading operations?

Comment: Yes, but according to your needs - you don't want to get the opposite issue, which is to get orphan related entities. Anyway yes, that's the cause of your problem.